# Stuck on Dawnguard Quest Prophet

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I'm doing the quest Prophet, but I'm stuck.

After talking to the guards in Dragon Bridge, I went to the south of the bridge but there was no overturned carriage, just an arrow indicating where it should be. What am I missing?

Comment: What quest is this?

Answer (score 3):

The quest you are on (Prophet) will be slightly different depending on which side you are with.

However, in both cases, you are supposed to find a note on a dead vampire that points you towards [Forebear's Hideout](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Forebears%27_Holdout).

I would try heading there to see if you can skip the note finding part of the quest.

If that doesn't work, you can get around this on the PC via the console:

Dawnguard quest:

> setstage DLC1VQ03Hunter 60

Vampire quest:

> setstage DLC1VQ03Vampire 60